# Representing experimental conditions/groups in R with one variable, when raw data uses 3

Tags: r, statistics

How can I transform values of three separate variables in R to create new values in a single, combined variable? I have experimental data with three conditions, 'negative', 'control', and 'pro'. The data in raw form gives information about who was in what condition (each participant/row could only be in each condition) by putting a '1' next to a variable named for that condition, then the value is missing if a participant was not in that condition. I would like to create a single variable called "Manip", with values of -1 (for those with the value of 1 in the negative condition), 0 (for those with a value of 1 in the control condition), and 1 (for those in the pro condition). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your data frame is named `df`

```
df$Manip[df$negative==1] <- -1
df$Manip[df$control==1] <- 0
df$Manip[df$positive==1] <- 1
```

Alternatively you could also make this a fancy factor, like so

```
df$Manip[df$negative==1] <- 'negative'
df$Manip[df$control==1] <- 'control'
df$Manip[df$positive==1] <- 'positive'
df$Manip <- as.factor(df$Manip,
                      levels=c(-1,0,1),
                      labels=('negative','control','positive'))
```